# iPhone : How to change titlebar text/font colour in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode, titanium, appcelerator

I'm currently building an app in Appcelerator Titanium 1.2.1.

I've been able to set the apps' titlebar/navbar colour using the following:

```
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup(
{
    barColor:'#fff'
});
```

Problem is, with a white titlebar, the text becomes hard to read. Is it possible to change the text colour from white to another colour? (say 'black' for contrast)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[posted solution below](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1484840648/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-change-text-style-in),  basically create a label and set the window title with the control

http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1484840648/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-change-text-style-in

Comment: The link above is broken, are you able to post instructions into the answer?